# Is the relation between <iframe> and it's document one way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, iframe, dom-traversal

You can get the nodes of the `document` object of an `<iframe>` with the `contentDocument` property of the [`HTMLIFrameElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLIFrameElement)

But I can't find a way getting the `<iframe>` back out of the node.
Is the relation between the `<iframe>` and it's document is only one way?
If it does, **WHY?**

[A non working DEMO:](http://jsfiddle.net/DjSec/)

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe');
var doc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;

var div = doc.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];

console.log('Did we find the iframe? ' + ($(div).closest('iframe').length > 0));​
// Output: "Did we find the iframe? false"
```

Comment: you should be able to get the div. why are you looking for it in that way? why not just get it directly?

Comment: I don't think the document has any information about what contains it. You would have to go to the window for that information which isn't handled by jQuery. The document inside of the iframe is an entirely separate DOM, you can't traverse from one to the other using only jQuery.

Comment: Actually, yes you can traverse from one to the other, but it requires methods such as .contents() which is one-way.

Comment: Using `console.log($(div).parents())` is a good way to represent this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `iframe` element is in different `document` (it's an element in the main page) than the `div` element (it's an element in the iframe page).

You can get the `iframe` element like this:

`iframe.contentWindow.frameElement === iframe`

Or when inside the `iframe` script environment:

`window.frameElement`

Or using the `div`

`div.ownerDocument.defaultView.frameElement === iframe`

[Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DjSec/3/)

Comment: +1, when I got out of bed this morning, I didn't know how to get the parent `document` or `window` object from an element; now I do.

Answer (score 0):

thing is, for `(div)` in the `console.log` line, they are part of the frame, they don't know they are in a frame so `.closest('iframe')` will be empty.

Comment: Basically the div is not part of the document that the iframe is contained in.